# Not handling error properly for invalid filter value in ldapjs client API

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, apacheds, ldapjs

The ldapjs client API is not throwing proper error when passing incorrect filter data.

Below is code snippet:

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs')
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://<<ldap host>>:389'
})

client.bind(<<LDAP Admin User>>, <<Password>>, function(err) {
  if (err) {
      console.log('Error :  ', err)
  } else {
    let searchOpts = {
        scope: 'sub',
        filter: 'cn',
        attributes: []
    }
    client.search('dc=test,dc=com', searchOpts, function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error***************', err)
      } else {
        let count = 1
        res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
          console.log('entry  : ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object))
        })
        res.on('page', function(result, cb) {
          console.log('page end', result.controls)
        })
        res.on('error', function(err) {
          console.error('error: ' + err.message)
        })
        res.on('end', function(result) {
          console.log('result: ' + result)
          client.unbind(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error unbind : ', err)
            } else {
                console.log('unbind is success')
            }
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Here, we are passing incorrect filter parameter.

```
D:\node_modules\ldap-filter\lib\index.js:200
      throw new Error(expr + ' is invalid');
      ^

Error: cn is invalid
    at _buildFilterTree (D:\node_modules\ldap-filter\lib\index.js:200:13)
    at _parseString (D:\node_modules\ldap-filter\lib\index.js:411:17)
    at Object.parse (D:\node_modules\ldap-filter\lib\index.js:422:12)
    at Object.parseString (D:\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\filters\index.js:176:25)
    at Client.search (D:\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:769:30)
    at D:\ApacheDS\apacheds_test_retrieve.js:29:12
    at sendResult (D:\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1395:12)
    at messageCallback (D:\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1421:16)
    at Parser.onMessage (D:\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1089:14)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

Here, it is not throwing any error from ldapjs error http://ldapjs.org/errors.html. It seems the error handling is not implemented properly.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's not implemented properly. An invalid filter is something you should be able to fix during debugging and realistically should never happen in a live application. The errors in that list are errors either in contacting the server, or errors the server itself returns - stuff that may still happen in a live application, which your code would need to handle appropriately.

Comment: Thank you @GabrielLuci for your quick inputs. We are implementing client application using `ldapjs` library and as per user the invalid filter should be marked as HTTP 400 error. Here, the `ldapjs` library is not handling the invalid filter errors which is effecting client implementation. Could you please advise on handling the invalid filter as HTTP 400 error with this limitation with `ldapjs`. Thank you.

Comment: I have raised issue for the same here. https://github.com/ldapjs/node-ldapjs/issues/618

Comment: Looks like they've already replied.